# What is the probability that the first collision occurs at the Kth insertions?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, hash-function

### Question

> Consider a hash table with $n$ buckets, where external (overflow) [Chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Separate_chaining) is used to resolve collisions. The hash function is such that the probability that a key value is hashed to a particular bucket is $\frac{1}{n}$.  The hash table is initially empty and $K$ distinct values are inserted in the table.
>   What is the probability that the first collision occurs at the $K^{th}$ insertions?

### Approach

> For the first collision occurs at the $K^{th}$  insertions,
>   Insertion from $1$ to $k-1$ should not collide and then at $k^{th}$ itteration it should collide.

Insertion from $1$ to $k-1$ should not collide
$$=\frac{n}{n} \times \frac{n-1}{n} \times \dots \times \frac{n-(k-2)}{n}$$

But i am not getting how to derive probaility for $k^{th}$ itteration collisions
please help me out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. The probability for the $k$-th insertion to produce a collision, given that the first $k-1$ insertions haven't, is $\frac{k-1}n$, as $k-1$ buckets are occupied. Thus the overall probability for the first collision to occur at the $k$-th insertion is

$$
\frac{n!(k-1)}{(n-(k-1))!n^k}\;.
$$

Comment: i got your point that final answer will be



$\frac{n}{n} \times \frac{n-1}{n} \times \frac{n-2}{n} \times ..\frac{n-(k-2)}{n} \times \frac{k-1}{n}$

$=\frac{n!}{(n-(k-1))!} \times \frac{k-1}{n^k}$

but i am not getting

"The probability for the k-th insertion to produce a collision, given that the first $k−1$insertions haven't, is $\frac{k−1}{n}$ as $k-1$ buckets are occupied"

  because $k-1$ insertion have not faced collisions so at kth insertion we have probability as $\frac{k}{n}$

Comment: @laura: I don't understand how you arrived at $\frac kn$. If $k-1$ items have been inserted without causing a collision, then $k-1$ out of $n$ buckets are now occupied. If we uniformly randomly select one of these $n$ buckets for the $k$-th item, the probability that we'll hit one of the $k-1$ occupied buckets is $\frac{k-1}n$.